thinkpad yoga touchscreen calibration
I have a "Lenovo ThinkPad X1 2-in-1 Gen 9" and have ubuntu 24.04 installed. The finger touchscreen works fine. However the digitizer calibration is wrong and is always closer to the center of the screen than it should be.
I've tried:

xinput_calibrator. This only accepts the first input through the digitizer then rejects all additional input not from finger touch
OpenTabletCalibrator. This did not recognize any devices. For reference under power settings the pen is listed as a Wacom HID 5397
Libinput.calibrate-touchscreen defaults to finger input and targets are not visible onscreen
weston-calibrator. This accepts finger input, but it is unclear how to alter the input mode

Additionally I have tried taking the output from xinput_calibrator (finger touch) and apply it using instructions from How would I calibrate a tablet pc (pen input only) screen?. I believe this did not work since 24.04 is running wayland and merely simulating X behavior using xwayland.
As such I have started to follow these instructions https://canonical-mir.readthedocs-hosted.com/stable/how-to/how-to-calibrate-a-touchscreen-device/ and ran into an additional problem. udevadm info -q property /dev/input/event6 (which is the correct folder) returns
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-1/i2c-WACF2200:00/0018:056A:5397.0002/input/input17/event6
DEVNAME=/dev/input/event6
MAJOR=13
MINOR=70
SUBSYSTEM=input
USEC_INITIALIZED=3379341
ID_INPUT=1
ID_INPUT_TABLET=1
ID_INPUT_WIDTH_MM=301
ID_INPUT_HEIGHT_MM=188
ID_SERIAL=noserial
ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:15.1-platform-i2c_designware.1
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_15_1-platform-i2c_designware_1
LIBINPUT_DEVICE_GROUP=18/56a/5397:i2c-WACF2200:00
DEVLINKS=/dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:15.1-platform-i2c_designware.1-event-mouse
TAGS=:snap_libinput_replay:snap_libinput_record:snap_libinput_list-devices:snap_libinput_debug-events:snap_libinput_analyze:snap_libinput_mea>
CURRENT_TAGS=:snap_libinput_replay:snap_libinput_record:snap_libinput_list-devices:snap_libinput_debug-events:snap_libinput_analyze:snap_libi>

This doesn't contain the vendor id and model id used in the udev rule.
I have two questions.

Is there a way to choose device id on weston-calibrator or a better calibrator that I have not already tried?
Is there another way for me to set the udev rule without the vendor and model id rule

Thank you for your help
The following is output from xinput list in case that helps
WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:15                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:15              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer-gestures:15              id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-touch:15                         id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-tablet stylus:15                 id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-tablet eraser:15                 id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-tablet cursor:15                 id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:15                      id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]

UPDATE: I have tried and succeeded in manually altering the libinput calibration matrix. However, I do not believe this is working as intended
I am using the current calibration matrix and have confirmed that the udev rule is being applied
0 1 0 1 0 0
To my understanding this should reverse inputs. However I end up with exactly the same behavior as when it is using the identity matrix. As a follow up question what could be the source of this issue?

For what it's worth, I have obtained the best results with touchscreen-laptops by installing Kubuntu with KDE Plasma.
https://kubuntu.org/
